# How to query from mutiple tables and group them by DATE in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, date, group-by

I want to get data from two tables and group them by date, like a daily report that shows data from two tables.

Example output:

| Date | Active User | Total Deposit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-31 | 10 | 12500 |
| 2023-08-01 | 5 | 10000 |
| 2023-08-02 | 20 | 20000 |
| 2023-08-03 | 3 | 100 |

## Migrations

```
users
-id
-created_at
...
```

```
deposits
-id
-user_id
-amount
-created_at
```

## Models

```
users
public function deposits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Deposit::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

```
deposits
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

## Edit

What I've tried so far, I can query from single table and group them by date, but when it comes to joining two tables into a single query, I'm lost. I dont think I can use UNION or UNION ALL for this, neither LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN as I want to get ALL data from the table USER and DEPOSIT.

`Deposit::select(DB::raw("date(created_at) as date, SUM('amount') as total_deposit)->groupby('date)->orderBy('date')->get();`

`User::select(DB::raw("date(created_at) as date, count('*') as active_player->groupby('date)->orderby('date')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could be helpfull to you.

```
$combinedData = DB::table('users')
->select(
    DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as date"),
    DB::raw("COUNT(users.id) as active_players"),
    DB::raw("SUM(deposits.amount) as total_deposit")
)
->leftJoin('deposits', DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at)"), '=', DB::raw("DATE(deposits.created_at)"))
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at)"))
->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at)"))
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to join users at all here. You need to query only deposits and calculate distinct `user_id` values from the same table, without joining.

Try this:

```
Deposit::selectRaw("DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(distinct user_id) as active_players, SUM(amount) as total_deposit")
  ->groupBy('date')
  ->orderBy('date')
  ->get();
```